# Send different emails through Sitecore 9.2 Forms without EXM?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm upgrading a project from Sitecore 9.0.2 to Sitecore 9.2.

The old project was using WFFM for all of their forms, and now they must all be moved to Sitecore Forms.

One of the business requirements is for the submit action on most of the forms to send an email once the user clicks "submit". The emails details differ from one form to another.

I wanted to ask if there is a way to achieve this in Sitecore 9.2, **without using EXM?**

I have been searching with no luck, Sitecore forms extensions uses EXM, and writing a custom submit action would mean hardcoding the contents of the email, which means creating a separate custom action for each form we have, this is a really big number of forms and feels like a bad approach, since the content editors wont be able to change the emails without someone changing the code itself.

**Is there no custom module or way to be able to choose different email details for each form, whilst using the same code for the basic "send email" custom submit action? like there was in WFFM?**

EDIT: I have checked this suggested [link](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/13392/3547), but the accepted answer's links are mostly not working, and "You need to setup Form Designer to substitute fields with keywords like {Subject} or {From}"" is a little vague

Comment: I think you should be able to add a custom submit method and use SendGrid.

Comment: @mie follow the link https://sitecorediaries.org/2021/09/08/creating-custom-submit-action-to-send-the-emails-in-sitecore-forms/

Comment: @Rameshkumar the link doesn't help much my use case, as I need the emails to not be hardcoded into the code, Im looking for a way to make it so the content editor can pick different email formats based on the form they are using